# is there a way to find list of valid locales in my linux using perl?

Tags: linux, perl, locale

I need to find a list of locale installed/supported in my linux machine.
is there a way to find a list of valid locales in my linux using perl ?

thanks

Answer (score 47):

This command will give you a list of locales:

```
locale -a
```

From a Perl script you can execute the same using

```
system("locale -a");
```

Answer (score 10):

If you want the list of all supported locales, in my Debian distro they are in `/usr/share/i18n/SUPPORTED` , so you could do:

```
system("cat /usr/share/i18n/SUPPORTED");
```

Comment: This one actually works  :) +1   An alternative is :  `less /usr/share/i18n/SUPPORTED` which of course provides you with the option to search for a "locales of interest".

Answer (score 2):

```
my @locale_list = `locale -a`;
chomp(@locale_list);
```

Answer (score 2):

http://perldoc.perl.org/perllocale.html#Finding-locales:

> For locales available in your system, consult also setlocale(3) to see whether it leads to the list of available locales (search for the SEE ALSO section). If that fails, try the following command lines:

```
locale -a
nlsinfo
ls /usr/lib/nls/loc
ls /usr/lib/locale
ls /usr/lib/nls
ls /usr/share/locale
```

Answer (score 0):

if by saying "valid locales" you wanted to check which locales are `supported`

then you need to go to the file (you can open it with 'nano' to check if it is still there)

```
nano /usr/share/i18n/SUPPORTED
```

tested on Ubuntu 18